# Chrome Offering To Save Password on Registration Form - Ajax

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, forms, validation

I have a registration form and when everything checks out and the registration button (submit button for the form) is clicked, it runs all of the following code. the /xhrCreateUser method in my PHP controller further validates, sanitizes, and inserts the POST data into a database. For simple error checking for now, if the echo from the /xhrCreateUser method is `true`, then it alerts the user that the account has been created and it redirects the page. However, when the redirect method is called, the browser offers to save the password when the user is redirected. I would like this behavior to happen on something like a login form, but not a registration form. If the redirect is not called, the Offer to save the password does not trigger, so obviously it is that that is triggering chrome to offer to save the password. I don't get why this is happening, it does not do employ this behavior in Firefox. Is it something to do with me posting the value of a password input element or something?

I imagine chrome does this to support ajax login forms, but its also doing this on my registration form, which is not ideal.

```
register.addEventListener('click', function(e){
    if(validateName(0)){

        if(validateName(1)){

            if(validateUsername(2)){

                if(validateEmail(3)){

                    if(validatePassword(4)){

                        //Start XML HTTP Account Insertion
                        var xmlhttp;

                        if(window.XMLHttpRequest){
                            xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
                        } else {
                            xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                        }

                        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function register(){
                            if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200){
                                var result = xmlhttp.responseText;
                                console.log(result);
                                if(result.indexOf('true') > -1){
                                    alert("Account has been created, you will be redirected");
                                    redirect();
                                    //redirect
                                } else {
                                    alert("Something went wrong, that's all we know. Please refresh the page and try again.");
                                }
                            }
                        }

                        xmlhttp.open("POST", "user/xhrCreateUser", true);
                        xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/json");
                        xmlhttp.send(JSON.stringify({firstname:firstname.value, lastname:lastname.value, username:username.value, email:email.value, password:password.value}));

                    } else {
                        //password is bad
                        //toggle error classes for CSS here
                        forceError(4);
                        password.focus();
                    }

                } else {
                    //email is bad
                    //toggle error classes for CSS here
                    forceError(3);
                    email.focus();


                }
            } else {
                //username is bad
                //toggle error classes for CSS here
                forceError(2);
                username.focus();

            }

        } else {
            //lastname is bad
            //toggle error classes for CSS here
            forceError(1);
            lastname.focus();

        }
    } else {
        //firstname is bad
        //toggle error classes for CSS here
        forceError(0);
        firstname.focus();
    }
});
```

Comment: you might be able to trick chrome by using setTimeout("redirect();",10) to break the connection between the submit and the navigation, which sounds like is what triggers the offer

Comment: I was hoping that would solve it however it does not

Answer (score 0):

### Solved

#### Making the POST synchronous and not asynchronous worked by changing `true` to `false` in the `xmlhttp.open` line worked.